# Unwanted characters in messages downloaded with RMAIL

Tags: email, character-encoding

I use RMAIL as my default Email client and it works well for my purposes. I have one small problem with it that I cannot resolve. Downloaded messages include unwanted characters in one heading, the `Return-Path:` heading. So a typical incoming email looks like this when RMAIL is running:

```
\377Return-Path: <example@email.com>
```

Note **\377**

If I open the actual RMAIL file, the line looks like this:

```
ÿReturn-Path: <example@email.com>
```

The Emacs Manual speaks of this problem but offers a vague solution by advising the user to "guess" the right encoding system.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rmail-Coding.html

I have tried various options but none seem to work.

I run Emacs 27.1 on Windows 10.